# Xpages Date Time Picker field defaults to today's date

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

Running a ND9 server and when browsing a Xpage with a date field, the default value for this field is always today's date.

On a 8.5.3 server the control is rendered like this:

```
<input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" dojoattachpoint="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" type="text" aria-valuenow="undefined" aria-invalid="false" id="view:_id1:_id2:main:fromTDate" tabindex="0" value="">
<input style="display: none;" type="text" name="view:_id1:_id2:main:fromTDate">
```

On a ND9 server the same control renders like this:

```
<input class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-invalid="false" tabindex="0" id="view:_id1:_id2:main:fromTDate" maxlength="10" size="10" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="view:_id1:_id2:main:fromTDate" value="2013-03-26">
```

I've been able to circumvent it by adding a Dojo Date Text Box instead but this feature must be wrong, right?

Comment: It's probably a bug in R9, you should open up an support issue about it.

Comment: Some advocates of UX design suggest that date fields should have sample values to show the date format expected, so it's up to discussion. But Fredrik is right: support will tell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was actually a fix put into v9.0. Today's date appearing by default is now the expected behaviour

Comment: One person's fix is another person's bug.

Comment: Will that be added to the Dojo control as well?  Will there be a property to opt out of the default?

Comment: IBM has said that this will be fixed in 9.0.1 and will return to the expected behavior of no default date. I'm extremely happy about that.

Comment: seems IBM fixed in 9.0.1. http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/fixlist.nsf/Public/1A9AB544F8DA5BAA85257C0C0041F39E?OpenDocument

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your XPage and the behavior is like in 8.5.3

```
<xp:this.resources>
<xp:script clientSide="true">
<xp:this.contents><![CDATA[
require([
"dojo/_base/lang",
"ibm/xsp/widget/layout/DateTextBox",
"ibm/xsp/widget/layout/TimeTextBox",
"ibm/xsp/widget/layout/DateTimeTextBox"
], function(lang, DateTextBox, TimeTextBox, DateTimeTextBox){
var a = {};
lang.mixin(a, {
postCreate: function(){
this.inherited(arguments);
}
});
DateTextBox.extend(a);
TimeTextBox.extend(a);
DateTimeTextBox.extend(a);
});
]]></xp:this.contents>
</xp:script>
</xp:this.resources>
```

Thanks IBM for the fast response.