# DatePicker Default to Today

Tags: javascript, datepicker, xpages

I know this is probably very simple, but what I'm trying isn't working. I'm just trying to get my Date Picker on my XPage to default to today's date. I've tried the following:

```
var dt:NotesDateTime= session.createDateTime("Today"); dt.setNow();
```

and

```
session.evaluate("@Today")
```

and

```
var doc:NotesDocument = currentDocument.getDocument();
var dt:NotesDateTime = doc.getCreated();
dt.setAnyTime();
return dt.getLocalTime();
```

No matter what I try, the Date Picker is unchanged.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation of your date picker? You may have to call a function similar to `myDatePicker.update()` to force the object to accept your change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is an example of setting today's date as the default value for a date field (for which a date picker has been attached):

```
<xp:inputText id="Date" value="#{document.date}" defaultValue="#{javascript:@Today()}">
    <xp:dateTimeHelper id="dateTimeHelper1" />
</xp:inputText>
```

---

Please notice that IBM Domino 9.0 had a bug where all date fields had today's date as the default value. You should upgrade to 9.0.1 (or use the workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15780768/785061).

Comment: Yes I was aware of the bug, but I am still using 8.5.3 here, but thanks!