# XPages - how to remove default value from date fields?

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I'm using several Edit Boxes on an XPage. These Edit Boxes use the display type Date/Time and are designed to store and display date values. On my test server these Edit Box fields contain no default value when a new XPage is being created. On my production server the current date is always displayed as a default value. What could be the cause of this? Here is my code:

```
<xp:inputText id="Birthdate" value="#{document1.Birthdate}" defaultValue="">
<xp:this.converter>
<xp:convertDateTime type="date"></xp:convertDateTime></xp:this.converter>
<xp:dateTimeHelper></xp:dateTimeHelper>
</xp:inputText>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/15632042/785061

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a change in Domino 9 but it has been changed in 9.01

Check this previous question about this and the solution

[Xpages Date Time Picker field defaults to today's date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632042/xpages-date-time-picker-field-defaults-to-todays-date/15739528#15739528)

Comment: Ah, that's why I don't see it any longer on my 9.0.1 test server... ;)