# xpages default value for combobox

Tags: xpages

I found this : [Xpages Date Time Picker field defaults to today's date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632042/xpages-date-time-picker-field-defaults-to-todays-date/15739528#15739528)

I tried adding `return null` as default value for my combobox, but it still returns the first item from the list.

I also tried adding a formula item: `@Text("")`, but even if the default value is blank, it appears also as an item for the combobox.

Please help, thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.  Can you explain a little better please?  It sounds like you want the default to be blank but then you don't want to have a blank option in the list?

Comment: @DavidLeedy Thanks for your response. Well, what I want to do is when the document / xpage is loaded the combobox default value to be "", as it is in classic Lotus Notes designer/programming.

Comment: this is a java solution but in this video I show some different ways to work with Comboboxes..  http://notesin9.com/index.php/2014/03/13/notesin9-138-xpages-combobox-improvements/

Answer (score 2):

One thing I do often for defaults..  and I forget if I do this for Comboboxes or not.  But I'll bind the control to a viewScope variable.  Then in beforePageLoad I'll set that viewScope variable to "" basically.  I find this works better then the "default" option on the pretty properties pain.  Maybe you want to give that a try.
In THEORY if that works then it will be blank to begin with.. but once it's changed you might probably can't put it BACK to blank.  In order to to that you'd need to have a blank option at the top of your values list.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that there is a better way to do this, but....

I always use a normal item ojbect with one single space written in as the label and value.  Under that I put my calculated values.  Then for the default value, I put " ".  It might not be pretty, but it gets the job done.  When I read the value, before asking if it is empty, I just use @Trim() to make sure that it is indeed a real value.

Of course you could make the label a single white character space with a value "empty" and then use "empty" as your default value.  The label would then be a single white space character.